# Php displaying username /username

Tags: php

I just wanted to know if i can display my logged in username such as http://website.com/username /username would be the username and to display the username on profile.php how can i display that in a echo? or variable here is my ht accesses below if needed

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?user=$1
```

Comment: Even if you get this working, This should NOT be used to manage user sessions. Seriously.

Comment: Side note: only one RewriteRule is needed:  `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['user'])) {
    echo $_GET['user'];
}
?>
```

or short version:

```
// Use outside php tags
<?=(isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : "guest")?>

// use inside php tags
echo (isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : "guest");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo $_GET['user']; ?>
```

Comment: Don't trust user data!

Comment: Of course not. This was just to demonstrate how to get that variable.

Answer (score 0):

filter the data you get from the url

```
<?php 
$user = filter_var($_GET['user'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

echo $user;
?>
```

Comment: You forgot the $ at echo user ;)

Answer (score 0):

anything that is in the url with this type: `page.php?var1=x&var2=2`
can be accessed via the global $_GET array because it's a variable sent by get protocol.

so the var1 and var2 in my example can be found in `$_GET['var1'], $_GET['var2']`.
and in your case if the page is `website.com/profile.php?username=SomeUser`
you can use `$_GET['username']`.

One last thing, NEVER under any circumstances, use the user input accessed through the global
arrays directly in your code, evaluate it, clean it, escape it, what ever you need , then use it.